# Saltos de linea en Java

Tags: java

B dias! he creado un programa que crea un txt, seleccionando el nombre y el contenido, y me funciona perfectamente. He añadido saltos de línea y todo, pero debería terminar el bucle al escribir "q" y NO lo hace, alguien sabe por qué?
Os paso código de lo que tengo hecho.

```
public class practicas04 {

static InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //crear archivo


    String ruta = System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator;
    String salt = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    System.out.print("Introduzca el Nombre del Archivo: ");
    String file = br.readLine();

    System.out.print("Introduzca el Contenido del Archivo: ");
    String text = br.readLine();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (ruta+file+".txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);
    bw.write(text+salt);
    bw.flush(); //obliga al buffer a escribir en el archivo.

    while (text != "q") {   
        text = br.readLine(); 
        bw.write(text+salt); 
        bw.flush();  
    }//end while

    bw.close(); 
    System.out.print("El Archivo "+file+".txt se ha Creado con Éxito! en\n "+ruta);

}//end main
```

}//end class

Comment: Los saltos de línea son con Alt+Enter

Comment: No es esa la finalidad de la pregunta, el "usuario" no tiene porqué saber esa combinación de teclas, ni siquiera se le debe dar bien la informática. Pero Gracias por tu aporte. LO que quiero es que el "usuario" cierre la escritura al pulsar una tecla concreta, por ejemplo.

Comment: Si el salto de línea es el enter y no la finalización, ¿qué tecla será la finalización.?

Comment: Cuando pulsas Enter no es que se cierre el programa, es que termina la función `readLine()` que como su nombre indica, lee una línea que termina cuando llega el salto de línea, tecla Enter. Si quieres que pueda seguir escribiendo, tendrás que volver a llamar a `readLine()`, hasta que se cumpla la condición de salida, que la verdad, no me imagino cómo podrías hacerla...

Comment: Gracias! me has dado una idea. Voy a intentarlo.

Comment: Casi conseguido, pero no termina el programa al escribir "q", es lo único que me falta. He añdido un do while (text!="q");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del while, en la línea `br.write(textAr+salt);)`, que es textAr? ¿No debería de ser text?

```
    while (text != "q") {   
    text = br.readLine(); 
    bw.write(text+salt); 
    bw.flush();  
}//end while
```

He probado cambiando el while y ahora funciona, siempre y cuando la "q" sea la primera letra de una línea.

```
 while (!text.equals("q")) {
     text = br.readLine();
     bw.write(text+salt);
     bw.flush();
 }//end while
```

Comment: Si xavi, ya está cambiado. Como lo estoy haciendo en dos .java, he mezclado nombres de variables. Gracias!

Comment: Perfecto!! ya funciona. He probado también (text != ("q")) pero NO funciona. Tu respuesta funciona perfectamente!!

Comment: Creo que es porque con String se tiene que usar .equals para comparar.

Comment: Exacto!! los operadores  de == y != no funcionan con variables String. Muchas Gracias Xavi. Acabo de enterarme.